# Changing the desktop file name width under 18.04

Tags: unity, 18.04, icons, fonts, resize

The width allowed for the name of a file on the desktop under 18.04 seems to have shrunk dramatically compared with 16.04. The result is that names wrap in strange ways. I have tried resizing the font using the Unity Tweak Tool. The width of the region does not change. As I make the font smaller and smaller, more appears. However, under 16.04 I was able to make the font larger, for my eyes.

Comparison of text width for the names of files on the desktop in 16.04 and 18.04:

[image: Comparison of text width for the names of files on the desktop in 16.04 and 18.04]

Is there any way to increase the size of the width that is allowed for the text below the icon on the desktop?

Comment: Consider adding tag(s) to the shell you are actually using (assume you are using Gnome).

Comment: Not much you can do if you want to use nautilus as default file manager & fm to handle the desktop. You could try setting the view size of icons to 67% , that may present less crappy word wrapping. than the default which is 50%

Comment: Juan, I am new to this and thought that Ubuntu 18.04 ran Unity. How would I check? Thanks!

Comment: Doug, would I use the Unity Tweak Tool to change the view size of desktop icons to 67%? When I open "File" click on "Desktop" then on the logo with three horizontal bars I can see how to make the desktop icons larger. Unfortunately, many of the files on the desktop seem to disappear outside the visible region of the desktop when I do that. With 16.04 the icons were smaller but the text was larger, and spanned a larger region. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is everywhere! Each and every folder has icons shoved together and wrapped letter by letter. There must be a way to increase the horizontal spacing between folders in all settings. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this but involves a number of steps. Essentially the idea comes from here: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/05/change-desktop-icons-size-ubuntu-19-04/

What you have to do:

1. Install Gnome tweaks
2. Install the [Gnome Desktop-Icons extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1465/desktop-icons/)
3. Change in a text file the 'width' of symbols. The file is located in your home folder at:

   .local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/desktop-icons@csoriano/prefs.js

For this, open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> then type in:

```
gedit .local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/desktop-icons@csoriano/prefs.js
```

There change the following value:

```
const ICON_WIDTH = { 'small': 200, 'standard': 200, 'large': 200 };
```

Of course, if `200` is to wide or to narrow for your liking you can make the value bigger or smaller.

4. To avoid double drawing of icons by the extension and Gnome, use Gnome tweaks to switch of the regular drawing of desktop icons.
5. Restart Gnome to see the result.